# Template engine for android

Tags: android

I am looking for a template engine for Andorid like Apache Velocity for Java.
I have already found Common Template Engine (https://code.google.com/p/commontemplate), but there is no user manual.

Do you know any other template engine? Have you any experiences with it?

Thank you very much

Comment: If anyone comes past this post I can also recommend https://github.com/bkiers/Liqp (Liquid java port). Unfortunately this https://github.com/HubSpot/jinjava (jinja2 java port) doesn't work on Android.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Chunk](http://www.x5software.com/chunk) is perfect for Android projects.

It has a small footprint but plenty of built-in functionality. The {$tag} syntax is straightforward and easy to learn.

With Android in mind, the docs include an extension example that [loads templates from a web server](http://www.x5software.com/chunk/examples/ChunkExample?example=net&loc=en_US#input-more-EG1), so you can change the templates without having to release a new version of your app.

Full disclosure: Chunk is my own open-sourced template engine.